# JavaFX Virtual keyboard is showing in Netbeans but not in distribution

Tags: javafx, touch, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to make javaFX virtual keyboard work for touch screen. All goes good in Netbeans.

I put this in Project->Properties->Run->VM Options:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true    
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true    
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx
```

When I run the program in Netbeans, the keyboard shows up, when I click in a textField it's working...all good.

The problem is when I build the application and I run the .jar from the dist folder, no more keyboard...

Any idea? Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you set the system properties when running the JAR file?

Comment: @Slav What do you mean? I've tried last night to put `<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
  <fx:platform>
   <fx:property name="-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded" value="true"/>
   <fx:property name="-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch" value="true"/>
   <fx:property name="-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard" value="javafx"/>
  </fx:platform> 
 </target>` in build.xml.... But no changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters in the main function.

```html
System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The VM Properties have to be loaded before running the main function...

Comment: My function


        ` System.out.println("Main");
        Class<?> app = Class.forName("ma.sofisoft.Main");
        Method main = app.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
        System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", ".");
        Object[] arguments = new Object[]{args};
//        main.invoke(null, args);
        Application.launch(args);`